# How can I set the height so that the scroll bar at the bottom of grid doesn't cover grid rows?

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

I have a react kendo grid like this: [Kendo grid with scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3seq1.png)

Right now, when there is data, there's a max of 10 rows. The grid height is dynamic, so if there's only 5 rows of data, the grid is smaller than if there are 10 rows, and as you see in the picture, there are no rows of data.

My question is: how do I add the height of the scroll bar so that the content is not clipped below the scroll bar, as shown here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the KendoReact packages. I have a similar case and the scrollbar is height enough to show the message.

[Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8yodei?file=index.html)

Comment: Thanks, but for mine I need the data to run off the page in the x-direction, because otherwise it's too small. So I do need the horizontal scroll bar. The problem is that the scroll bar isn't added to the bottom of the data, but rather over the data, and thus cutting some off so that you need to use a vertical scroll as well. I want to avoid this. Any tips?

Comment: @JustinFolk I checked with a scrollbar and the message is still visible.
Please share some code to better understand the case.
[Updated Grid](https://www.screencast.com/t/Cxs7PVAywYnf)